# Ruby on Rails: сохранение выбранного значения в select_tag

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Как сделать так чтобы `select_tag` сохранял выбранное значение и его не приходилось выбирать заново, к примеру, когда я хочу обновить :name или другие значения.

```
<%= form_for(@name) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lname %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :lname %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tag %><br />
    <%= f.select :tag, "<option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option>".html_safe, include_blank: true %>  
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

names_controller.rb

```
class NamesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @name = Names.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @names = Name.all
  end

  def new
    @name = Name.new
  end

  def create
    @name = Name.new(params[:name])
    if @name.save
      sign_in @name
      flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
      redirect_to @name
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @name = Name.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @name = Name.find(params[:id])
    if @name.update_attributes(params[:name])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @name
      redirect_to @name
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: покажи контроллер

Comment: пробывал добавить :onсhange => remote_function(edit_name_path(value)) не помогает

Comment: блин, вроде всё правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел решение   <%= f.collection_select(:tag, [1,2,3,4], :to_i, :to_s, :prompt => 'Категории') %>